# CountInstancesWithStatus returning empty response

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript

I'm trying to get a count of all instances of a workflow by status. Below is the code I'm using. I have not been able to find a lot of information about WorkflowInstanceService.CountInstancesWithStatus from googling. The only thing I was able to find was this blop post.

http://www.bluepowersolutions.com/2017/04/14/How-to-get-the-number-of-suspended-workflow-instances-in-a-SharePoint-list.html

All I'm setting with this is an empty response. Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function GetWorkflowStatus(subscriptionId, wfCountCellID){
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var workflowServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, context.get_web());
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
var subscription = workflowSubscriptionService.getSubscription(subscriptionId);
context.load(subscription); 
var stats = [1,4,5,6];
execute(context).then(function() {
    stats.forEach(function (st){
        var wfResp = workflowInstanceService.countInstancesWithStatus(subscription, st);
        var count = wfResp.get_value();
        execute(context).done(function() {
            document.getElementById(wfCountCellID + st).textContent = count;
        }).fail(function(message) {
            console.error(message);
        });
    });          
});
```

};

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out based on below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eacfe6ff-0fd5-436a-866b-5ce64b4495c6/countinstanceswithstatus-returning-empty-response?forum=sharepointdevelopment

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetWorkflowStatus(subscriptionId,workflowStatus){
    $.getScript("/_layouts/15/sp.js", function () {
        $.getScript("/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js", function () {                 
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var workflowServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, context.get_web());
            var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();
            var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
            var subscription = workflowSubscriptionService.getSubscription(subscriptionId);
            context.load(subscription);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function() {
                    $.each(workflowStatus,function(statusName, val) {
                        getCount(context,workflowInstanceService,subscription, val).done(function(result){
                            console.log(statusName+":"+result);
                        });     
                    }); 
                },
                function() {
                    console.log(arguments[1].get_message());
                }
            );          
        });
    });
}
function getCount(context,workflowInstanceService,subscription, status){
    var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
    var wfResp = workflowInstanceService.countInstancesWithStatus(subscription, status);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var count = wfResp.get_value();
            defer.resolve(count);
        },
        function() {
            defer.reject(arguments[1].get_message());
        }
    );
    return defer.promise();
}
$(function () {
    var subscriptionId="B7EACCFC-8760-4660-BC04-CC7C0A400FA3";   
    var workflowStatus ={
                           NotStarted : 0,
                           Started : 1,
                           Suspended : 2,
                           Canceling : 3,
                           Canceled : 4,
                           Terminated : 5,
                           Completed : 6,
                           NotSpecified : 7,
                           Invalid : 8
                       };
    GetWorkflowStatus(subscriptionId,workflowStatus);
});
</script>
```